MS Power Apps producing unwanted duplicate records
world! I've started a new position recently and have been struggling to find out why the code below is creating duplicate records within the popMode = "Move" section.
It's written in MS Power Apps and the code is to assign students to a particular group. When added initially students group is set to 0. I can then move the student to another group 1 or 2. Student is deleted from group 0 and a new record is created in either group 1 or 2.
The problem is when I try to move students from group 1 to 2 for example the code seems to be creating a new record in group 1 and 2 resulting in unwanted duplicate records.
I'd like to either remove the original record or update it to the new group.
If(
    popMode = "Add",
    RemoveIf(
        tt_tgroup_membership,
        student_id = popListStu_1.Text && tgroup_id = popListGroup_1.Selected.tgroup_id
    );
    Patch(
        tt_tgroup_membership,
        Defaults(tt_tgroup_membership),
        {
            student_id: popListStu_1.Text,
            tgroup_id: popListGroup_1.Selected.tgroup_id
        }
    ),
    popMode = "Copy",
    ForAll(
        check_stu,
        Patch(
            tt_tgroup_membership,
            Defaults(tt_tgroup_membership),
            {
                student_id: ThisRecord.student_id,
                tgroup_id: popListGroup_1.Selected.tgroup_id
            }
        )
    ),
    popMode = "Move",
    ForAll(
        check_stu,
        Patch(
            tt_tgroup_membership,
            If(
                ThisRecord.tgroup_id = 0,
                Defaults(tt_tgroup_membership),
                LookUp(
                    tt_tgroup_membership,
                    student_id = ThisRecord.student_id && tgroup_id = ThisRecord.tgroup_id
                )
            ),
            {
                student_id: ThisRecord.student_id,
                tgroup_id: popListGroup_1.Selected.tgroup_id 
            }
        )
    )
);

Refresh(v_tt_student_enrols);
ClearCollect(
    student_groups,
    Filter(
        v_tt_student_enrols,
        cost_id = current_cost.cost_id
    )
); Clear(check_stu);
UpdateContext({popVis: false});

I've tried adding:
RemoveIf( tt_tgroup_membership, student_id = ThisRecord.student_id && tgroup_id = ThisRecord.tgroup_id );
and:
Remove( Filter( tt_tgroup_membership, student_id = ThisRecord.student_id && tgroup_id = ThisRecord.tgroup_id ),
after check_stu,
but neither of these had the desired effect.
Thanks in advance for any help!

I am assuming that there's a collection called student_groups and it has a column which specifies the group, 0, 1 or 2.
I'd create a gallery with the source student_groups and add a dropdown in the template. On the dropdown with items [0,1,2], I can put a patch function on the onchange trigger to change the group value, like, Patch(student_groups,ThisItem,{GroupColumn:Self.Selected.Value})

That's great. Thanks Ken. The dropdown with available groups function works well.
I have a list of student records. Can select with checkboxes (good for grouping more than one at a time). And buttons for 'Add' 'Copy' and 'Move'. Add and copy are irrelevant at this stage but clicking Move creates the duplicate records. I'm guessing removing the buttons and forcing users to use the drop down is a suitable workaround. Might come back to this one another time when I've got a better understanding of the whole system!
